# First Google script - save data in xls and file upload

Tags: google-apps-script

New to GAS and am struggling with my first script. Any help will be appreciated.
The UI displays but I cannot write data in a xls file. It was working when I was using a handler, however, I had to change it to a doPost to get file upload to work.

I want to have UI that has several fields and 2 file upload options. Does anyone have sample script that I can use to get started?

My script

```
function doGet(e)  
 Create a vertical panel with a grid that has  text boxes
 Create a form that has a file upload box 


function doPost(e) { 
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Auxvh5UNOiURdE1uc1VOVGNlTE01bjF4THRmdzFnSXc'); 
var lastRow = doc.getLastRow();
var cell = doc.getRange('a1').offset(lastRow, 0);
cell.setValue(e.parameter.universityname);
cell.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.parameter.eventname);to age 
cell.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.parameter.city);

var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);


 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
 app.close(); 
 return app; 
}
```